# Determining Social Referrals in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I have a question about social referrals in Google Analytics:

Firstly, 
When I go here: 
Acquisition -> Channels -> Social

a significant portion of my Social Networks is recorded as "not set". Why is this ?

Secondly, which is more reliable for gauging social media referrals:
Acquisition -> Channels -> Social
or
Acquisition -> Social -> Overview

The figures in both sections are different.

Answer (score 2):

Acquisition reports **group data from various channels**, so that's why the **Overview in Social reports has different numbers**. Look at Admin ~ Channel Grouping (see attached screen). The default setup might not be the best and most precise for your web, so have a look at the setting and adjust if needed.

The reason you might see *(not set)* value in your reports is that some of your campaigns are probably not tagged correctly. [URL Tag Builder](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en) tool by Google might be of help in such case.

[image]